# ESP8266 Soft WDT Error

Tags: esp8266, watchdog

How can I avoid the `Soft WDT reset` Error in this loop.
The Error consistently occurs when reaching the number 3190.

```
unsigned long TimeFrame = 10000;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
    unsigned long StartTime = millis();
    while (millis() - StartTime <= TimeFrame){
        Serial.println(millis() - StartTime);
    }
}
```

I could count 4 times to 2500 but would this be the correct approach to this error?

Thanks for the explanation. I added a `delay(10)` to the code and it works.

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
    unsigned long StartTime = millis();
    while (millis() - StartTime <= TimeFrame){
        Serial.println(millis() - StartTime);
        delay(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WDT is the "[watchdog timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer)". Watchdog timers are used to get control back when something goes wrong in a system - say, an infinite loop or some other unexpected condition. When the underlying system gets control back it resets these timers so that they start counting up from zero again. When they hit their maximum value they trigger a hardware reset on the chip.

Your code measures the duration of the ESP8266 software watchdog timer - in this case 3.19 seconds.

The ESP8266 has both hardware and software watchdog timers. `loop()` isn't intended to run indefinitely - it's intended to do a small amount of work and then return.  When it returns, the ESP8266 SDK gets to reset the watchdog timers.

Both the `delay()` and `yield()` functions give the SDK a chance to say "things are okay" and reset the timers. If you need to have long running code in `loop()` you should call one of those occasionally to give the rest of the system a chance to run.

Keeping `loop()` brief isn't just about the watchdog timer, either. It also gives the network stack a chance to run and do processing that it needs to do.

You should always design your program so that `loop()` does a small batch of repetitive processing and then returns. It should never contain an infinite loop or long loop of code.

For instance, suppose you need to do something every 20 seconds. This is the wrong way to do it:

```
void loop() {
  unsigned long start = millis();

  while(millis() - start < 20*1000) ;

  do_something();
}
```

That breaks the way the software is designed to work - with `loop()` executing briefly. It doesn't allow any other software to run while it's waiting. The watchdog timer will fire and reset your CPU.

This is better:

```
void loop() {
  delay(20*1000);

  do_something();
}
```

because `delay()` lets the underlying system get control back, reset the watchdog timer and also do network-related processing.

In my opinion, this is best:

```
static unsigned long start_time;

void setup() {
  start_time = millis();
}

void loop() {
  if(millis() - start_time > 20*1000) {
    do_something();
    start_time = millis();
  }
}
```

because it does the least possible work inside `loop()`, only when it's time to do the work.